# How in Python can I get dataframe coordinates that are not items in a column, into columns within the same dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-xarray

I am using xarray to read in two different netCDF files, using combine='by_coords'. The data read in is then converted to a dataframe, and the printed output is shown below.

```
                                            tag          p
lat       lon         time
23.025642 -110.925552 2010-01-01              0        NaN
                      2010-01-02              0        NaN
                      2010-01-03              0        NaN
                      2010-01-04              0        NaN
                      2010-01-05              0        NaN
...                                         ...        ...
29.974609 -90.084259  2010-12-20              0   9.711414
                      2010-12-21              0   8.313345
                      2010-12-22              0   6.525973
                      2010-12-23              0   1.124200
                      2010-12-24              0   0.000000

[64110060 rows x 2 columns]
```

The variables are put as columns, however the coordinate variables are not columns. I have tried pulling the lat and long separately and appending them to the dataframe, however that is not working (size differences).

How might I be able to get the lat and lon as columns, so I can then use pandas groupby function with these?

Comment: How are you converting to dataframe? Are you using `.to_dataframe`?

Comment: Yes, I am using `.to_dataframe` @Maximilian.

Comment: Can you show a reproducible example? It's difficult to see what's going on without that, unfortunately. Also, to the extent you're converting to pandas to do groupby, xarray supports that and lots of other transformations.